# Learning Nunjucks (Jinja2) How can I pass JSON data to the views correctly?

Tags: javascript, json, templates, jinja2, nunjucks

I'm learning how to nunjucks and I understand how to use templates but cannot properly figure out how to insert data from json objects.

Here is my attempt I was able to hard code it into the template itself as a variable.  But how can I source it from an external source out side of the template?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Pass the required parameters when calling `Nunjucks.render`, like this:

```
nunjucks.render("items.html", { items: [ ... ] });
```

`items` will be available on top of the default `foo` variable set globally. In the template (items.html) you can simply access `items` like you do now (just remove the declaration of `items` from the .html.

Answer (score 1):

Working code without `&quot;` everywhere (JSONstringify like)

```
var myVar = {{ myData | dump | safe }};
```

Answer (score 0):

nunjucks escapes html by default you have to tell it explicitly that you input is "safe" using the `safe` filter. Let say your JSON string is in `myData` and you wanted to use it as a javascript variable `myVar` you would write in your template:

```
var myVar = {{ myData | safe }};
```